# How do I receive multiple paragraphs from a user in Ruby2.6.3?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to receive multiple paragraphs at once from a user.

I've tried using gets, but it doesn't seem to be working... it discards the second paragraph:

```
#The code:
   print("Paste your text here: ") 
.. essay = gets 
.. puts(essay)

# Getting user imput (the second sentance is a separate paragraph)
Paste your text here:  I like cake.
 It makes me happy.

# What the computer did for puts(essay):
I like cake.
=> nil
```

I expected the result to be something like this:

```
"I like cake.\nIt makes me happy.\n"
```

But it gave me `"I like cake."` instead.
How could I end up with my expected result?

Comment: How do you want the user to indicate to you that they're done inputting paragraphs?

Comment: if a user pastes in text already containing separate paragraphs, the paragraphs will still be separated by a new line. Pressing enter (after pasting the text) will end the input.

Comment: In a console, a newline pasted in and a newline caused by the user pressing 'enter' are indistinguishable. You'll need some kind of sentinel value. For instance, you could have the user type "QUIT" when they're done and look for that message, or you could have them hit enter twice in a row, provided the inputted text doesn't have any double newlines.

Comment: That sounds awesome!!!

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add paragraphs to a string until the input consists of a empty line:

```
str  = ""
para = "init"
str << (para = gets) until para.chomp.empty? #or para == "\n"
p str
```

Comment: is `p str` the same as `puts(str)?

Comment: `p` is short for `puts str.inspect`. `p` is a tool for you, the developer: Ruby, show me what this is.

Comment: This can be shortened using the `$_` global variable: `str = ""; str << gets until $_ == "\n"`

Comment: What if I want to also use the gets to delete any UTF-8 characters received by this gets...I dont exactly know how to use the `:encoding => 'UTF-8'` code

Comment: All characters which you receive by `gets` are UTF-8 by default.

Comment: here is the full error: ...`:in \`split': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)`

Comment: @I_love_coffee This has really nothing to do with your original question. If you have a new question then formulate a new question. By doing so other people will be able to find it and perhaps learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, with a slightly different logic

```
def getps
  save, $/ = $/, "\n\n"
  gets.chomp
ensure
  $/ = save
end

str = getps
```

The global variable `$/` is what Ruby uses to find out what line end is. `gets` gets things till line end. If we tell Ruby that line end is two newlines, then `gets` waits till we have two newlines in a row till it exits. Since we don't need them, we'll just chomp them off. The rest of the code is just to ensure that `$/` gets restored properly afterwards so normal `gets` is not messed up forever.